# Actionscript: Blur everything except one object

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am using the following to blur an object

```
var blur:BlurFilter = new BlurFilter(); 
blur.blurX = 10; 
blur.blurY = 10; 
blur.quality = BitmapFilterQuality.MEDIUM; 
obj.filters = [blur];
```

I then moved to

```
root.filters = [blur];
```

Which blurs everything, but I want to not blur one object, so everything underneath it is blurred.

Can this be done.

I tried

```
obj.filters = [];
```

To turn it off on one object but course this did not work.

Comment: In order to do this you need to have the non-blurred object **outside** everything else. Like, make another container attached directly to the **stage** and move/copy the object in question there.

Comment: @organis, thanks, that worked.